# mod_rewrite in XAMPP localhost and Magento 2

Tags: magento

I followed this tutorial http://www.appseconnect.com/how-to-install-magento-2-on-xampp-server-localhost/ to install Magento 2 on XAMPP (Windows).

After install magento, I open the project and admin on browser and when I see the firebug console there countless errors when trying to access js, css and fonts of the folder pub/static:

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try with `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command. If still not working then try below link for useful information given by dedicated developers. Thanks.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/no-images-or-js-on-new-magento-2-installation